# Не отправляются письма с сайта

Tags: php, email

Написал `php` код для отправки письма с подтверждением регистрации на сайте:

```
$Code = base64_encode($_POST['email']);
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Подтверждение регистрации на сайте';
$message = 'Ссылка для подтверждения регистрации: http://engine.esy.es/account/activate/code/'.substr($Code, -5).substr($Code, 0, -5);
$headers = 'From: administration@engine.esy.es';
mail ($to, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251',$subject), iconv('utf-8','windows-1251',$message), $headers);
```

Код рабочий, т.к. письма действительно отправляются, но отправить можно на почту, которая создана на хостинге (hostinger), а на другие электронные почты, например: mail, gmail, yandex письма попросту не доходят.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: смотрите логи, где-то в /var/mail/* или в /var/log/syslog (возможно, где-то еще) должна быть ошибка на отправку

Answer (score 1):

Причина может быть в том, что ваш хост не поддерживает функцию `mail()`. Попробуйте выяснить, можно ли отправлять почту через SMTP (с аутентификацией или без неё).
Если это можно, возьмите любой класс для отправки почты, хоть какой-нибудь PHPMailer (я в своё время [написал](https://github.com/Oire/OireMail/) простенький класс для себя сам — было интересно, как работает SMTP).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй на сервере через ssh выполни

```
echo "123" | mail test@gmail.com
```

Должно прийти письмо или ругнутся, что-тот типа

```
    /usr/lib/sendmail: Нет такого файла или каталога
"/home/alex/dead.letter" 8/199
. . . message not sent.
```

Может и в спам попадать.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда сразу смотрите логи

```
fgrep -r 'ящикполучателя@mail.ru' /var/log
```

В логах вся правда. Скорее всего проблема черных списках и/или спаме. Для снижения риска попадания в спам в отправителе указывайте реальный почтовый ящик + не забудьте так же про [DKIM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) и [SPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

Или воспользуйтесь сторонним сервером отправки почты, например [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) или отправляйте через `SMTP`